# How to select a jagged block in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, there are some text like this:

```
001 aaaaa
002 bbbbbbbb
003 ccc
```

I want to select

```
aaaaa
bbbbbbbb
ccc
```

and yank it. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The following sequence should do the trick**

```
ggw<C-v>G$
```

**where**

```
gg    -- Goes to top of file
w     -- skips one word
<C-v> -- starts visual block select
G     -- selects until end of file
$     -- selects to end of each line
```

Comment: `gg` goes to the top of the buffer, `0` goes to the first column on the line. ***edit*** oh OK, you changed it as I was writing this comment.

Comment: @romainl - I catched it *jit* <g>.

Comment: Thank you, the `$` is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `Visual Mode` in Vim by pressing `v` in prompt

place the `cursor` in the `column` to `select`

Use `ctrl+v` to select a block to copy

Then the column alone will be selected and copy  needed text alone and can yank it:)

[Please refer the link here](http://sethmason.com/2007/09/27/vim-tip-select-column.html)

Comment: It doesn't work, because of 'ccc' is short than the two other line.